# How can I tell which version of Windows 8 I am running? Standard, Pro, Enterprise, or RT?

Tags: windows-8

I have searched everywhere but cannot find how to tell which version of Windows 8 I am running.  I have the system properties on the screen but it just says "Windows 8," nothing else.

Is this the standard edition?

EDIT 04142015:  My new favorite way to do this is to go to the commnand prompt and issue (same with Windows 7):

`wmic os get caption`

Response:

```
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
```

Comment: Your update should have been an answer itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect it is the standard edition.

I have Pro and it shows as Windows 8 Pro as per the image below.

[image: Windows 8 Pro]

Alternatively, you can try the following from the command line:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
```

[image: Windows version from command line]

Answer (score 8):

To complement the other answers, I have Windows 8.1 Basic Edition, and the System Properties shows just "Windows 8.1".

[image: System Properties Windows Edition - "Windows 8.1"]

In PC Settings -> PC Info, the same information is available:

[image: PC Settings Windows Edition - "Windows 8.1"]

This should complement the screenshots of the other editions shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

It will tell you on the System properties screen (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>).  I'm running Win 8 Pro and it reflects that:

[image]

If yours just says "Windows 8" then I would say you are running the standard version.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to check your windows version is to open cmd.exe and type:

> slmgr.vbs /dli

Wait a few moments, here's what mine says:

```
Name: Windows(R), Professional edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
```

So, I am running Windows 8 Professional Volume Licensing

Comment: The other answers seem to work fine. This may be the most unreliable way once Windows 8.1 is available, as it doesn't indicate the version number.

Comment: Can you advise how the previous answers are incorrect? given `systeminfo` gives a lot more details the `slmgr.vbs /dli`

Comment: @DarkReverser, Why do you say this is the only way to check windows version?

Comment: You can update Windows 8 to 8.1 for free.  You can't update Windows Basic to Widows Pro for free, so this answer is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Windows/System32/license.rtf, it should say exactly which Windows version you are using.

This method is useful when you are trying to determine your Windows version from an offline Windows partition (when you boot into a Linux for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to 'Control Panel' on your computer, go to 'System and Security' On the 3rd bar down it'll say 'System' click on that tab, then it should say info about your computer.

Another way to find information out about your model go to the search (swipe left and search) type in 'winver' and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the mouse in the lower right hand corner of the screen and choose "Search" then type "cmd.exe". Next, type slmgr.vbs /dlv

You will get a detailed description about the original licensed install for Win8 OS on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `winver` or `msinfo`.

Comment: You mean "msinfo32"?

Answer (score 0):

Boy this info is tough to find if Windows won't boot to the desktop and you need to know what operating system you are working with. I was eventually able to find all the information normally found in the 'Properties' page when right-clicking 'Computer' in 'Explorer' in the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ (in one form or another). 
If booting to a Windows desktop typing 'Windows Key' + 'R' will bring up a run dialog, next you would type 'regedit' in the box and navigate to the above key.
Viewing this information offline is a little harder but the following page presents two good options for looking into the registry: http://www.wintips.org/how-to-edit-and-modify-registry-offline/

Hopefully this will be of use to the next person in my predicament...

Comment: You should provide the relevant information from that website.  You should also take the chance,while your providing the relevenat information from that website, to use formatting to make your answer easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Try running "winver" (Windows version).  (Type `winver` into the `Run...` dialog or a Command Prompt window.)

Comment: Of course it's because this doesn't work............