# How can I detect which Windows 8 version I have?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

A few hours ago I bought a new ASUS N56 laptop (VZ 4215H).

It has Windows 8 on the HDD, I've bought an HDD caddy and an SSD.

1. Is there a program that can move the OS to the SSD?
2. How can I detect which Windows 8 version I have (Home/Pro/Ultimate) so I can download the ISO if there is no answer to question one?

I think I have the Home version. Is it true that the Windows 8 key is stored on the motherboard?

Comment: Related: [Free way to clone HDD to SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free way to clone HDD to SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd), [Easiest way to move my Windows installation to an SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/252675/easiest-way-to-move-my-windows-installation-to-an-ssd), [How can I tell which version of Windows 8 I am running? Standard, Pro, Enterprise, or RT?](http://superuser.com/questions/524828/how-can-i-tell-which-version-of-windows-8-i-am-running-standard-pro-enterpris) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a program that can move the OS to the SSD

There are dozens of programs that exist, more then likely, the manufacturer of your SSD device offers one that does exactly this.  If they don't then this question has already been asked before.

You can try one of the solutions offered in this question: [Easiest way to move my Windows installation to an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/252675/easiest-way-to-move-my-windows-installation-to-an-ssd?rq=1)

> How can I detect which windows 8 version i've (home/pro/ultimate) so I
>   can download the iso if there is no answer on question one.

There are only two versions of Windows 8 being sold to a consumer like yourself:

1. Windows 8 "**Core**"
2. Windows 8 Professional

You can determine which version by doing the following:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> which opens the charm.

Select **Control Panel** and navigate to `Control Panel\System and Security\System` this will display your system properties which include which `Windows Edition` you have exactly.

> I think I have the home version. Is it true that the Windows 8 key is
>   stored in the motherboard?

**Yes**

Comment: @JochemTheSchoolKid - Your welcome.  Its a good question ( how to determine which version of Windows 8 ) which has not been specifically asked already.

Comment: @Ramhound: [How can I tell which version of Windows 8 I am running? Standard, Pro, Enterprise, or RT?](http://superuser.com/questions/524828/how-can-i-tell-which-version-of-windows-8-i-am-running-standard-pro-enterpris)