# Which Windows 8.1 edition am I running

Tags: windows-8.1

There are several editions of Windows 8.1: Enterprise, Pro etc. I wan't to make sure, I am running correct edition.

When I go to PC info, I see `Edition: Windows 8.1`.
How can I figure out which version am I running?

Comment: If it does not say `Single Language` nor `Professional` nor `Media Center` when you hit properties on `My PC` then your running `Windows 8` which is known as `Windows 8 Core` the same applies to 8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell which version of Windows 8 I am running? Standard, Pro, Enterprise, or RT?](http://superuser.com/questions/524828/how-can-i-tell-which-version-of-windows-8-i-am-running-standard-pro-enterpris)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Run window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) type: `cmd /c "slmgr /dli"`

You should see something like this:

```
Name: Windows(R) BLAH edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, BLAH channel
...
License status: Licensed
```

### Alternative Solution

You can also use WMI to query the OS information using this command:

```
wmic os get Caption, Version, OperatingSystemSKU, OSProductSuite
```

You should see something like this:

```
Caption                                OperatingSystemSKU  OSProductSuite  Version
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Single Language  100                 768             6.3.9600
```

OS SKU codes [are explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://techontip.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/microsoft-directaccess-group-policy-wmi-filter-explained/). 100 (0x64) stands for `PRODUCT_CORE_SINGLELANGUAGE`

OSProductSuite codes [are explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 768 (0x300) = 512 (0x200) + 256 (0x100)
This means **Windows Home Edition is installed** and **Terminal Services is installed, but only one interactive session is supported**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see "Core edition" does it means that I cannot enable Hyper-V on it?

Comment: No. Hyper-V is [only available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart) for Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise versions.

Comment: @Vinayak, Technically isn't it just a software issue? Shouldn't there be a way around this limitation, like a patch or fix we can apply or something?

Comment: @Pacerier You can [download Hyper-V Server 2012 for free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2). Read more about it [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/04/05/getting-started-with-hyper-v-server-2012-hyperv-virtualization-itpro.aspx)

Comment: `winver` is a lot easier to type compared to `cmd /c "slmgr /dli"` :)

Comment: @Rocky `winver` doesn't tell you what edition of Windows you are running

Comment: @vinayak It's right below the copyright date on Windows 8. Up at the top in Windows 7 and earlier.

Comment: @Rocky Oh yeah, I totally missed that. My bad.

Comment: @Vinayak, Weird, why is there free official installation now for Windows 8 non-Pro?

Comment: @Pacerier what do you mean "free"?

Comment: @Vinayak, We candownload Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 for free.

Comment: @Pacerier I haven't downloaded it so I can't say what's it's like but from the article I read, it's supposed to be a standalone version of Hyper-V

Comment: @Vinayak, Exactly, they are giving us free download of Hyper-V when it's supposed to be charged. (Availability of Hyper-V is [one of the differences](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx)  between Win 8.1 Core vs Win 8.1 Pro.)

Comment: @Pacerier [This article](http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/does-free-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012-have-same-hyper-v-role-features-found-windows-server) might answer that question.

Answer (score 5):

With PowerShell

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
```

To start PowerShell, hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (to open Run utility), type in powershell and hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

Open the command line (right click on window, then select `Run`), type `systeminfo.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

In the Run window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) type:

```
msinfo32.exe
```

This will give the user a very detailed system summary of hardware resources, components and software environment. On the System Summary page, the first field `OS Name` will identify the version and variant of the OS, such as `Microsoft Windows 8 Pro`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ver command. There might be some variants I am not aware of. It should print the version of your and / or the version of the command processor.

There are keys in registry in bottom that hold the value of the Ver.