# How do I find out which Windows 10 four-digit-version (not build number) am I running?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I currently face some problems with an update for Windows 10, and all guides, advice and troubleshoot sites out there start of by assuming you have specific versions of Windows 10 already running. But I am afraid I don't have those, since one of those numbers seems to be the update that gets stuck and doesn't finish correctly.

How do I see which version (not build number) of Windows 10 I'm actually running? All answers I've seen so far help you find which build number you have --since it seems more relevant for Windows apps developers--, but not the four-digit version number Microsoft is mentioning for troubleshooting the failed updates.

I've tried suggestions from a `Windows 8.1` related question ([Which Windows 8.1 edition am I running](https://superuser.com/questions/794083/which-windows-8-1-edition-am-i-running)); in particular I got some information with the following command line:

```
wmic os get Caption, Version, OperatingSystemSKU, OSProductSuite
```

but nothing of that seemed like the four digit number I see posted everywere (1511, 1607,...).

Also with `msinfo32.exe` and `systeminfo.exe` but still the same lack of 4-digit number.

Comment: Other questions I found focus on build number --as it is more relevant to developers--, but I was looking for the windows version number, to know if an update had taken place or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press the Windows Key + R to bring up the Run dialog window
2. Type `winver` and hit Enter

[image]

3. This brings up the About Windows dialog window and the second line shows the Version and Build number

[image]

Comment: Hey!! beat me at solving it... That's the one I was looking for. Here you have your points ;-)

Comment: You can type `winver` right in the Start search box, from at least Win 7. No need for the `run` box first.

Comment: How do you find this number from the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

## winver or about

Now I feel kind of stupid having asked a question that is answered directly in [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/how-do-i-see-what-version-of-windows-10-i-have/7e243675-7b85-4fda-aa2f-9430ce47749c). I'll answer it here, for the sake of those --like me-- that look first in Stack Exchange.

#### About

The answer is right in the about from within settings (not the System properties that you pop up with `Win + pause`): Settings -> System -> About

The number I was looking for is that at "Version".

#### Winver

You can also get that information with the `winver` command in either of the following ways:

1. Press `Win + R` then type `winver` and hit `return`
2. type `winver` at a command prompt or powershell then hit `return`
3. hit the `Win` key then type `winver` and hit `return`