# Which Windows 8.1 pro x64 version am I running?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, version

I realize there is a very similar question here...

Yet the provided answers to that question did not answer my question...
[this is 'that' question](https://superuser.com/questions/794083/which-windows-8-1-edition-am-i-running)
So there was an answer the first one on the page; which is cmd /c "slmgr /dli"

But the results are not very detailed. So Vinayak, had provided an alternative solution, which is a WMI to query the OS information using this command:
*'wmic os get Caption, Version, OperatingSystemSKU, OSProductSuite'*

When I got the script fired up it came back with this:
Line:1
Char:9
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
Source: VB Script compilation error

So what the heck am I doing wrong? Or is the code missing anything?

So to answer my question; No! I am not missing anything, but I have a word to many... Namely the first word in the code: wmic...   Also I used wmic.exe...

Comment: Where have you run the `wmic os get Caption, Version, OperatingSystemSKU, OSProductSuite` command?

Comment: @cemster with regards the wmic os get command, I have just successfully run it on my Windows 8.1 Pro machine, from the CMD prompt (not PowerShell)
I removed all spaces between the commas and added "/Format:List" to the end of the string i.e.
 
`C:\>wmic os get Caption,Version,OperatingSystemSKU,OSProductSuite /Format:List`

Comment: and this may help you understand and use wmic as well: [Rob Van Der Woude's Scripting Pages - wmic](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmic.php)

Comment: So yes! I was running it on Command Prompt. I realize and found wmick.exe and typed the code but I also failed to get a result. I have to read your link and then give it a go.                                                                                 The reason I am trying to get the specifics; if it is Single Language or SingleLang_EnglishInternational? With that information I need to 'Rufus' the correct Win8.1 iso to fix corrupted C++ situation I'm dealing with...     Thank you by the way

Comment: So yes again. But this time I realized that I shouldn't type the 'wmic' as part of the code...  I also just realized that you used CMD.. Huh.. I just fallowed your link and did it with wmic.exe..  Thanks again..  How do I select this, as an answer though is beyond me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why any scripts or commands are needed for what you want to know. (although the `wmic os get Caption` command works perfectly for me.)

The most user-friendly way to find out which edition of Windows you're rocking (i.e. RT, Home, Pro, Enterprise or Education) is to look in the System Properties windows.

Open the **Control Panel**. Choose **System and Security**. Click **System** (or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and the <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>), and on the top it will dispaly your Windows edition:

[image]